# Print value in an html page passed through Python

Tags: python, html

I am kinda new to the development of Heroku apps, and in general to the HTML world.

I have developed an application hosted in Heroku. The basic behavior of the page is that I have a splash page in which the user is asked to insert some parameters, I make some predictions on them (through Python), store them on a Postgresql DB and then redirect the user to another Html page via:

```
data = Searches(loc, ar, ba, fl, zo, yPrediction)
db.session.add(data)
db.session.commit()
return render_template('success.html',yPrediction)
```

The return render_template command redirects my app to "success.html" together with yPrediction. Till now the code is working fine, you can have a preview here [link](https://mccsapienza.herokuapp.com/). As you can see, if all parameters are correctly inserted the value is stored in the dband the user gets redirected to another html page.

What I would like to achieve is that that value stored in the db, which is yPrediction, gets printed in the success.html page. Something like:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="../static/logo1.png" alt="" class="logo" />
      <center><h3>Thank You!</h3></center>
      <center><h0>The price prediction for your apartment is YPREDICTION PRINTED HERE</h0></center>
      </div>

  </body>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your programming question is unrelated to the tags (e.g. heroku, heroku-postgres, python).  Your question is about displaying the value on the html page. And according to you Heroku, the database and the python script are working. There is also some spelling errors (elaborate/evaluate?) which makes it harder to understand. Please rework your question, provide a minimal, reproducable code of your problem and cut anything that is not needed out of your question. Provide error logs, etc. A single code line like that doesn't help us further.

Comment: Tin thanks again. I have updated my question, hopefully it's a little bit clearer.